# Firebase Cloud Function - parsing error: unexpected token dbRef

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make 2 requests on the Firebase RealTime database. First, I get an ID and then with the second request I will get a post that has that ID.

I tried replacing the first Promise with await, but it did not work. I've managed to make the code work with a Promise within another Promise, but I don't understand why it doesn't work like this, and I often stumbled upon this annoying error, so It's time to understand why it happens and how to fix it (not avoid!)

```js
exports.getFirstPosts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let dbRef = admin.database().ref();

    return dbRef.child('/regions/').child(req.query.region)
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            let data = snapshot.val();
            let message = "empty"

            if(data === null || data === undefined) { 
                message = "No-posts-in-region"
            }else{
                message = "success"
            }
            console.log(data);

            let postsIdsArray = [];
            for(let id in data){
                postsIdsArray.push(id);
                console.log('x',id);
            }

            let postData = await dbRef.child('/posts').child(postsIdsArray[0]).once('value')
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        version: "check if data is null 2post update",
                        message: message,
                        data: data,
                        arr: postsIdsArray,
                        post: snapshot.val(),
                    });
               
            
        });
});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\marius\Desktop\CloudF\functions\index.js
  77:34  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token dbRef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\marius\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-26T16_25_42_235Z-debug.log
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\marius\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\marius\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\marius\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Ok, I have added the error as text!

Comment: It is not 100% clear what you try to execute, since you never use the value of `postData`. Also, why do you try to use await? Just because it didn't work with the returned promise? Finally, the error in the title seems to be different than the error in your question! You may adapt your question to explain better what is your goal and what exactly you want to send as response.

Comment: It simply does not work like that, with 2 awaits or promise and await inside the promise. I am trying to display postData (forgot to put it in the response json)

The error in the title is in the question. '77:34  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token dbRef'